# AutoCompleteTextView is not completing me

Tags: java, android, xml

there is no error!
only this function should bring me results but it doesn't show nothing
just writing a word from the string search and nothing happens
what's missing?
adding some more code in the implement?
the list of the string(from firebase) is being shown on the screen BTW

```
public void autoSearch(View view) {
    //auto search complete for comunity list
    this.context = context;
    String array1[] = firebaseComunityListArr.toArray(new String[firebaseComunityListArr.size()]);
                    AutoCompleteTextView txt = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.myAutoComplete);
                    txt.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    txt.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array1));
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    txt.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {           
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {            
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {            
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:hint="search here"
        android:id="@+id/myAutoComplete"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myAutoComplete"/>



</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Does your Array have values?

Comment: yes - it is from the database on firebase... and it is shown on the screen                                                                                                          but when I write in the autocomplete it doesn't do nothing .. just like an edit text

Comment: Try changing `getContext()` to `context` and give me a feedback!

Comment: thank you for the help - I forgot to do this :                                      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, array1);

Comment: Oooh yeah its true or you could have just delete this line `txt.setAdapter(adapter);`